# Can anyone tell which code block does parallel operation and why?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await, task

Code Block 1 :-

```
var services1 = new service1();
var services2 = new service2();
var result1 = await service1.GetData();
var result2 = await service2.GetData();
```

Code Block 2 :-

```
var services1 = new service1();
var services2 = new service2();
var task1 = await service1.GetData();
var task2 = await service2.GetData();
Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);
```

today i got these question in my quiz..!

As options where to choose one from them CB1 or CB2.

[image]

Comment: The second example seems incorrect, are you sure that it isn't ```var task1 = service1.GetData();``` and ```var task2 = service2.GetData();```? Right now none of those examples will be processed concurrently.

Comment: @imsmn yes sure , i will put the question image pls see.

Comment: I don't think the 2nd one will compile unless the result of `GetData` is a task. Both code blocks are doing asynchronous work. I think whoever asked you the question messed up the 2nd question. I think they forgot to remove the `await` words in the 2nd block. Or they don't fully understand await/async.

Comment: As for doing parallel work, when a thread (T1) encounters `await`, it simply offloads the work and while that work is being done, T1 is free to either do work or simply wait. In both cases there is parallel work happening even. Waiting is also work.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Waiting can only be considered work if the thread is blocked. "Parallel" means that two or more threads are running at the same time. That only *might* happen in the second example. I gave a longer explanation in my answer.

Comment: No it can happen in both cases. `await` doesn't necessarily mean a second thread in some special cases, but in most cases there will be a thread. Also, waiting means work regardless of whether it is blocked. If it is blocked, for sure no parallel work. If not blocked, there may be parallel work.

Comment: Did you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is fine as long as `await service1.GetData()` does not throw an exception. If it does, then the result of, or any exeptions thrown by, `await service2.GetData()` will be lost.

It will, however, serialise the operations, as `service2.GetData()` will not be invoked until `service1.GetData()` has completed.

Your second example will not compile, unless you meant to do this:

```
var service1 = new service1();
var service2 = new service2();
var task1 = service1.GetData();
var task2 = service2.GetData();
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Where the `Task.WhenAll` is awaited rather than `service1.GetData()` and `service2.GetData()`.

Then you can safely access the results like this:

```
var result1 = task1.Result;
var result2 = task2.Result;
```

The difference here is that there is only one place that an exception can be thrown: `Task.WhenAll`, which will aggregate the exceptions from all provided tasks.

It will also allow `service2.GetData()` to be invoked whilst any asynchronous work done by `service1.GetData()` is executing.

---

There is a third option as well, assuming `service1.GetData()` and `service2.GetData()` have the same return type:

```
var service1 = new service1();
var service2 = new service2();
var results = await Task.WhenAll(services1.GetData(), services2.GetData());
```

That way, the result of each `Task` will be added to an array (here `results`).

You could then extract the individual values:

```
var result1 = results[0];
var result2 = results[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally I wouldn't answer a homework question, since you should have learned it in class. But I feel the need to answer the this one, because it's a bad question and I fear you are being helped to misunderstand asynchronous programming.

#### Parallel != asynchronous.

"Parallel" means that two or more pieces of code are being executed at the same time. That means there is more than one thread. It's about how code *runs*.

"Asynchronous" means that while a block of code is waiting for some external operation, the thread is freed to do some other work, instead of locking the thread. It's about how code *waits*.

Let's assume that `GetData()` makes a network request to get the data. This is what happens in that second example:

1. `service1.GetData()` runs until the network request is sent and returns a `Task`.
2. `service2.GetData()` runs until the network request is sent and returns a `Task`.

So far, both network requests have been sent and we're waiting for responses. Everything has happened on the same thread, not in parallel. But we still need to run the continuation of each (everything after `await` in `GetData()`) after each response is received. How those run depends on if the application has a synchronization context.

- If there is a synchronization context (ASP.NET, or UI app, for example) then nothing will run in parallel. The continuation of each call to `GetData()` will run one after the other on the same thread.
- If there is no synchronization context, (ASP.NET Core or console app or `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used inside `GetData()`, for example) then each continuation will run on a ThreadPool thread as soon as the responses come back, which may happen in parallel.

If your teacher wants you to put B, then put the answer that will get you the marks. But it might actually be wrong, unless you have been given more detail about the type of application and if it has a synchronization context.

Also, there should be an `await` before `Task.WhenAll()`.

Microsoft has an excellent series of articles about [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) that are worth the read. You will find the other articles in that series in the table of contents on the left of that first article.